# Can't ignore Playground files in git

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore, swift-playground

I've added a playground to my workspace which I want to be a part of the repo but I don't want to track changes to it. I've tried adding all the following to `.gitignore` but nothing works:

1. `./Playground.playground/*`
2. `Playground.playground/*`
3. `Playground.playground/Contents.swift`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ever figure this out?